# Installing Pandas on MacOs. Permission Error

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pandas, pip

I am trying to pip install pandas on a mac.  I have python 3.6 installed.

When I pip install in the terminal I get the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas'
```

Comment: This question had been asked at least 3 times in the past week, try going some google search before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly edit the error into a formatted code block by highlighting it and pushing ctrl+k so it is easier to read? Thanks.

Edit: Also, I just looked through and at the bottom it says permission denied. Try rerunning the command as an admin. I.E try this command:

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

Comment: Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You might have already noticed, Mac come with a built in Python, python 2.7. If you read your traceback: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py` it's pointing to the 2.7 dir. this dir is in the Library folder so you don't have permission to install to it.

But you state that you have Python 3.6 installed as well, so if you wanted to install to that indtead. Do `pip3 install pandas` or `python3 -m pip install pandas` this help specify the python version. And if you want to run python 3.6 in terminal, type `python3` instead of just `python`